# How to get sponsored metrics like clicks, impressions, reactions and engagement rates in LinkedIn API v2

Tags: api, linkedin-api

We are able to get daily organic share statistics using this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics

For example, we can get info using this URL:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity={org urn}&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY&timeIntervals.timeRange.start={epoch start time}&timeIntervals.timeRange.end={epoch end time}
```

But we also need info on sponsored metrics like clicks and impressions. 
The documentation directs us to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting for sponsored metrics but we cannot find the URL to use in the documentation. We just wanted to map the organic daily clicks/impressions together with the sponsored clicks/impresssions, similar to how LinkedIn shows line graphs in the Company Page (Admin View) -> Analytics -> Updates showing both organic and sponsored.

Providing us a sample URL using for example the {org urn} would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: we already have the permission in the scope `r_ads_reporting` but we still cannot get the URL needed

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve this now. It is mainly because aside from the admin access in the LinkedIn API app and admin access to the company page, the dev user must also have access to the sponsored statistics through the LinkedIn Campaign Manager (so that AdAnalytics will not return empty values).

Below is a sample call that may be made:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange.start.year={Year}&dateRange.start.month={Month}&dateRange.start.day={Day}&timeGranularity=DAILY&pivot=COMPANY&companies[0]=urn:li:organization:<Your_company_id>' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer redacted'
```